# Sum with group by xquery

Tags: sql, xquery, xquery-sql

I am trying to convert the following sql to

```
SELECT SUM((((1-Discount)*Quantity)*[Unit Price]))  AS AMOUNT 
FROM Orders 
LEFT JOIN [Order Details] 
    ON Orders.[Order ID] = [Order Details].[Order ID] 
WHERE ((([Order Date]) BETWEEN #1/1/2006# AND #2/1/2006#));
```

The orders and order details have a 1 to many relationship (1 is with orders)

The code I currently have displays the full price for each order details but however wont allow me to combine each total value of the order details together to get the full value.

```
for $orderdetails in doc("Order Details.xml")/dataroot/Order_x0020_Details
let $order := doc("Orders.xml")/dataroot/Orders[OrderID = $orderdetails/OrderID]

where xs:dateTime($order/OrderDate/text()) gt xs:dateTime("1996-04-06T00:00:00") and  xs:dateTime($order/OrderDate/text()) lt xs:dateTime("1997-04-05T00:00:00")

return 
<Invoice_Amounts>
{
    $order/OrderID
}
<Amount>
{
 sum(((1 - xs:double($orderdetails/Discount)) * xs:double($orderdetails/UnitPrice)) * xs:double($orderdetails/Quantity))
}
</Amount>
</Invoice_Amounts>
```

Sample of `Orders.xml`

```
<OrderID>10248</OrderID>
        <CustomerID>WILMK</CustomerID>
        <EmployeeID>5</EmployeeID>
        <OrderDate>1996-07-04T00:00:00</OrderDate>
        <RequiredDate>1996-08-01T00:00:00</RequiredDate>
        <ShippedDate>1996-07-16T00:00:00</ShippedDate>
        <ShipVia>3</ShipVia>
        <Freight>32.38</Freight>
        <ShipName>Vins et alcools Chevalier</ShipName>
        <ShipAddress>59 rue de l&apos;Abbaye</ShipAddress>
        <ShipCity>Reims</ShipCity>
        <ShipPostalCode>51100</ShipPostalCode>
        <ShipCountry>France</ShipCountry>
    </Orders>
    <Orders>
        <OrderID>10249</OrderID>
        <CustomerID>TRADH</CustomerID>
        <EmployeeID>6</EmployeeID>
        <OrderDate>1996-07-05T00:00:00</OrderDate>
        <RequiredDate>1996-08-16T00:00:00</RequiredDate>
        <ShippedDate>1996-07-10T00:00:00</ShippedDate>
        <ShipVia>1</ShipVia>
        <Freight>11.61</Freight>
        <ShipName>Toms Spezialitäten</ShipName>
        <ShipAddress>Luisenstr. 48</ShipAddress>
        <ShipCity>Münster</ShipCity>
        <ShipPostalCode>44087</ShipPostalCode>
        <ShipCountry>Germany</ShipCountry>
    </Orders>
```

Sample of `Order Details.xml

```
    <OrderID>10248</OrderID>
<ProductID>11</ProductID>
<UnitPrice>14</UnitPrice>
<Quantity>12</Quantity>
<Discount>0</Discount>
</Order_x0020_Details>
<Order_x0020_Details>
<OrderID>10248</OrderID>
<ProductID>42</ProductID>
<UnitPrice>9.8</UnitPrice>
<Quantity>10</Quantity>
<Discount>0</Discount>
</Order_x0020_Details>
<Order_x0020_Details>
<OrderID>10248</OrderID>
<ProductID>72</ProductID>
<UnitPrice>34.8</UnitPrice>
<Quantity>5</Quantity>
<Discount>0</Discount>
</Order_x0020_Details>
<Order_x0020_Details>
<OrderID>10249</OrderID>
<ProductID>14</ProductID>
<UnitPrice>18.6</UnitPrice>
<Quantity>9</Quantity>
<Discount>0</Discount>
</Order_x0020_Details>
```

Comment: Which version of the standard are you targeting? (XQuery 3.0 has explicit group by support).

Comment: It would be helpful if the code samples were cut down to the minimum that was relevant to this specific question; right now it's a lot of work to read through them for the relevant details.

Comment: The xml documents are in excess of 20,000 lines and therefore I have only put up a couple of sample text, however I am using X Query 1 in XML Spy

Comment: I realize that you've already cut down your examples, but they could easily be cut down further. They contain data (ShipCountry, ShipCity, etc) not relevant to the question; the sample query includes restrictions (such as date filtering) not relevant to the question; etc. The goal is to make something as simple and understandable by someone else who has a similar problem -- the more details there are specific to your own problem, the less useful the question and its answers are to others.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9676197/sum-and-group-by-in-xquery-with-1-xml-file

Answer (score 0):

So -- as I understand it, you already know how to do the join, so the thing to focus on is the sum operation. The easiest way to do this is by using a for loop to set a variable, which you can then use:

```
let $doc :=
    <docroot>
        <Order id="1">
            <Discount>0.05</Discount>
            <Quantity>3</Quantity>
            <UnitPrice>15</UnitPrice>
        </Order>
        <Order id="2">
            <Discount>0</Discount>
            <Quantity>15</Quantity>
            <UnitPrice>20</UnitPrice>
        </Order>
    </docroot>

(: collect the orders relevant to your query;
   in your "real" version you'll want to filter,
   or do your join, or whatever :)
let $orders := $doc/Order

(: generate a sequence containing the price for
   each such order :)
let $order_costs := 
    for $order in $orders
        return ((1.0 - xs:double($order/Discount))
                    * xs:double($order/UnitPrice)
                    * xs:double($order/Quantity))

(: generate your final result :)
return sum($order_costs)
```

You also could avoid a variable assignment by embedding the for loop within the argument to `sum()`:

```
return sum(for $order in $orders
           return ((1.0 - xs:double($order/Discount))
                    * xs:double($order/UnitPrice)
                    * xs:double($order/Quantity))
```

Comment: Charles, I appretiate your answer, but the let $orders is flagging up "XQuery Validation Error!
Unexpected token - "let $orders := $orderdeta"

Comment: Hmm. I don't have an XQuery 1.0 engine available with me here, and it works fine as-is on BaseX, so I'll need to get back to you later.

Comment: @PeterRoche The exact query I gave has no line `let $orders := $orderdeta`, and has been validated to work on XMLSpy.